# The lake's treasure

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

On the bottom of a lake there is a treasure !
...but what lake?
Who helps me find it ?

**(C) (CA) . (C) (D) (CA) (CB) () (D)


(CBA) . (BA) (CBA) (A) (A) (D) (C)**

Comment: I think this is a binary-coded decimal. If this was an 8421 encoding, we have D=8, C=4, B=2, A=1. This gives 45485608 on the first line and 7371184 on the second line. My next guess is that this are coordinates, but checking them fails to find a lake.

Comment: I have modify the description... :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we use @Element118's binary-coded decimal system, the problem of:

```
(C)(CA).(C)(D)(CA)(CB)()(D) 
(CBA).(BA)(CBA)(A)(A)(D)(C)
```

Can be translated to:

```
(4)(41).(4)(8)(41)(42)()(8)
(421).(21)(421)(1)(1)(8)(4)
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
45.485608
7.371184
```

When searching for these coordinates, we get:

> Lago di Teleccio - https://goo.gl/maps/JfKHtphpXZq

Comment: This is a relatively well-known system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal